# Usage of verb drag

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotations

Is this sentence valid usage of verb drag?

"my persistence dragged me to solve it"

I want to say that I solved challenges due to my persistence which "encouraged" me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are being given *encouragement* the verb to use is

> [push](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/push) - to press or urge to some action or course
>
> my persistence *pushed* me to solve it.
>   my teacher *pushed* me to take the class.
>   my girlfriend *pushed* me into marrying her.

"drag" implies against your will, thus the idiomatic phrase

> [dragged kicking and screaming](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/drag-someone-kicking-and-screaming)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use dragged.

Dragged, used figuratively, means that you did not want to solve the problem, but you were forced to do so, by an external force. But you did want to solve the problem so you weren't dragged.

Instead I would say "my persistence enabled me to solve the problem" The meaning is not quite the same but I think this is the meaning you should be aiming for.